# Working on login/register features, userInfor shows undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I don't know why it shows "{
userInfo: undefined
}", testing with postman making a post request was successful and I can get users info including the token but nothing shows on the redux devTools. Also when I try to login it says "Unsupported media type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json" in request." I don't know if it's related or not..

userReducers.js:

```
export const userLoginReducers = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { laoding: true };
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { laoding: false, userInfo: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { laoding: false, error: action.payload };

    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return {};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

userActions.js:

```
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
    });

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "/api/users/login/",

      { username: email, password: password },
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.detail
          ? error.response.data.detail
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Store.js:

```
import {
  legacy_createStore as createStore,
  combineReducers,
  applyMiddleware,
} from "redux";
//import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import {
  productListReducers,
  productDetailsReducers,
} from "./reducers/ProductReducers";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducers/CartReducers";
import { userLoginReducers } from "./reducers/UserReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducers,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducers,
  cart: cartReducer,
  userLogin: userLoginReducers,
});

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
  : [];

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
  : null;

const initialState = {
  cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage },
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
};
const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

LoginScreen.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Row, Col, Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
//import products from "../../products";
import Message from "../Message";
import Loader from "../Loader";
import { useNavigate, useLocation, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { login } from "../../actions/UserActions";
import LoginForm from "../LoginForm";

function LoginScreen() {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const redirect = searchParams.get(search.split("=")) || 1;

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { error, loading, userInfo } = userLogin;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      navigate(redirect);
      setSearchParams(searchParams);
    }
  }, [navigate, userInfo, redirect, searchParams, setSearchParams]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login(email, password));
  };

  return (
    <LoginForm>
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      {error && <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>}
      {loading && <Loader />}

      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="password">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          ></Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Button type="submit" className="mt-3" variant="primary">
          Sign In
        </Button>
      </Form>

      <Row className="py-3">
        <Col>
          New Customer?
          <Link to={redirect ? `/register?redirect=${redirect}` : "/register"}>
            Register
          </Link>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </LoginForm>
  );
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

Comment: When and where is `userInfo` undefined? What `"Content-type"` header values is the server/endpoint expecting?

Comment: "Content-type": "application/json", on the homepage, it shows undefined in the redux devtools, can't even login with any username since it give me that weird error ""Unsupported media type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json" in request."" @drew-reese

Comment: I fixed that json error, I was able to login but still "userInfo" undefined.. Can you take a look at it? @drew-reese

Comment: Where exactly is `userInfo` undefined? Where are you expecting it to be defined?

Comment: In the redux devtools. Login Success but in state I get nothing. Users info: id, name, username, password, email an token @DrewReese

Comment: Does `dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data });` have the correct `data` value you are expecting to unpack in the `USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS` reducer  case with `return { laoding: false, userInfo: action.payload };`? In other words, does the dispatched action have the correct expected payload?

Comment: I solved this too, I'm receiving info now. Having a register issue but still trying with it before opening another issue here @DrewReese